Extracting subsystem from system
I am trying to modify the mock_station_simulation example to use Toppra to optimize a piecewise polynomial trajectory. The plant has 18 total positions (2 for door hinges, 7 for the arm, 2 for the gripper fingers, and 7 for the foam block that uses quaternion orientation). I tried passing an 18 width piecewise polynomial trajectory to Toppra with the non-iiwa related positions zeroed-out. But that failed since the plant defines the foam block with quaternions which aren't supported in (Drake's implementation of?) Toppra.
I suppose the proper method is to send a subsystem of the plant that only contains the iiwa to Toppra, but I am not sure how to get the subsystem. I see documentation for GetSubsystemContext but not for anyway to get a subsystem (or subplant? or subdiagram?). Any tips for how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code for reference:
mock_station_simulation.cc
#include <limits>

#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "drake/common/eigen_types.h"
#include "drake/common/find_resource.h"
#include "drake/common/is_approx_equal_abstol.h"
#include "drake/examples/manipulation_station/manipulation_station.h"
#include "drake/geometry/drake_visualizer.h"
#include "drake/lcmt_iiwa_command.hpp"
#include "drake/lcmt_iiwa_status.hpp"
#include "drake/lcmt_point_cloud.hpp"
#include "drake/lcmt_schunk_wsg_command.hpp"
#include "drake/lcmt_schunk_wsg_status.hpp"
#include "drake/manipulation/kuka_iiwa/iiwa_command_receiver.h"
#include "drake/manipulation/kuka_iiwa/iiwa_status_sender.h"
#include "drake/manipulation/schunk_wsg/schunk_wsg_lcm.h"
#include "drake/math/rigid_transform.h"
#include "drake/math/rotation_matrix.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h"
#include "drake/perception/point_cloud_to_lcm.h"
#include "drake/systems/analysis/simulator.h"
#include "drake/systems/framework/diagram.h"
#include "drake/systems/framework/diagram_builder.h"
#include "drake/systems/lcm/lcm_interface_system.h"
#include "drake/systems/lcm/lcm_publisher_system.h"
#include "drake/systems/lcm/lcm_subscriber_system.h"
#include "drake/systems/primitives/matrix_gain.h"
#include "drake/systems/sensors/image_to_lcm_image_array_t.h"
#include "drake/systems/primitives/trajectory_source.h"
#include "drake/common/trajectories/piecewise_polynomial.h"
#include "drake/multibody/optimization/toppra.h"

namespace drake {
namespace examples {
namespace manipulation_station {
namespace {

// Runs a simulation of the manipulation station plant as a stand-alone
// simulation which mocks the network inputs and outputs of the real robot
// station.  This is a useful test in the transition from a single-process
// simulation to operating on the real robot hardware.

using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using drake::trajectories::PiecewisePolynomial;
using drake::trajectories::Trajectory;
using drake::systems::TrajectorySource;
using drake::multibody::Toppra;

DEFINE_double(target_realtime_rate, 1.0,
              "Playback speed.  See documentation for "
              "Simulator::set_target_realtime_rate() for details.");
DEFINE_double(duration, 10.0, "Simulation duration.");
DEFINE_string(setup, "manipulation_class",
              "Manipulation station type to simulate. "
              "Can be {manipulation_class, clutter_clearing}");
DEFINE_bool(publish_cameras, false,
            "Whether to publish camera images to LCM");
DEFINE_bool(publish_point_cloud, false,
            "Whether to publish point clouds to LCM.  Note that per issue "
            "https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12125 the "
            "simulated point cloud data will have registration errors.");
DEFINE_string(iiwa_starting_position, "",
              "A comma-separated list of seven joint angles (in radians) "
              "to set the starting position of the iiwa arm. "
              "If empty, the default starting position is used.");
  
VectorXd parse_starting_position(const std::string& flag_value) {
  VectorXd starting_position(7);
  if (flag_value.empty()) {
    starting_position << 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;  // default starting position
  } else {
    std::istringstream iss(flag_value);
    std::string token;
    int i = 0;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, ',') && i < 7) {
      starting_position[i++] = std::stod(token);
    }
    if (i != 7) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid iiwa_starting_position flag value. "
                               "Exactly 7 joint angles are required.");
    }
  }
  return starting_position;
}


int do_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);

  systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;

  // Create the "manipulation station".
  auto station = builder.AddSystem<ManipulationStation>();
  if (FLAGS_setup == "manipulation_class") {
    station->SetupManipulationClassStation();
    station->AddManipulandFromFile(
        "drake_models/manipulation_station/061_foam_brick.sdf",
        math::RigidTransform<double>(math::RotationMatrix<double>::Identity(),
                                     Eigen::Vector3d(0.6, 0, 0)));
  } else if (FLAGS_setup == "clutter_clearing") {
    station->SetupClutterClearingStation();
    station->AddManipulandFromFile(
        "drake_models/ycb/003_cracker_box.sdf",
        math::RigidTransform<double>(math::RollPitchYaw<double>(-1.57, 0, 3),
                                     Eigen::Vector3d(-0.3, -0.55, 0.36)));
  } else {
    throw std::domain_error(
        "Unrecognized station type. Options are "
        "{manipulation_class, clutter_clearing}.");
  }
  // TODO(russt): Load sdf objects specified at the command line.  Requires
  // #9747.

  // VectorXd pose_start(7); // Define the starting pose
  // VectorXd pose_end(7);   // Define the ending pose
  // pose_start << 0, -1, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0;
  // pose_end << 0, .5, 0, -2.25, 0, -1, 0;
  VectorXd pose_start(18); // Define the starting pose
  VectorXd pose_end(18); // Define the ending pose
  pose_start << 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  pose_end << 0, 0, 0, .5, 0, -2.25, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;

  // Create a vector of times at which the poses are defined.
  std::vector<double> times = {0.0, FLAGS_duration};  // Start and end times

  // Create a vector of Eigen vectors (poses) for the trajectory.
  std::vector<MatrixXd> poses;
  poses.push_back(pose_start);
  poses.push_back(pose_end);
  

  // Create a PiecewisePolynomial trajectory from the given poses and times.
  auto trajectory_first_pass = PiecewisePolynomial<double>::FirstOrderHold(times, poses);

  

  station->Finalize();

  // Calculate grid points for the trajectory discretization.
  drake::multibody::CalcGridPointsOptions options;
  auto& plant = station->get_multibody_plant();
  const auto gridpoints = Toppra::CalcGridPoints(trajectory_first_pass, options);
  std::cout << "Path rows " << trajectory_first_pass.rows() << '\n';
  std::cout << "Plant.num_postitions " << plant.num_positions() << '\n';
  // std::cout << "Plant actuator names " << plant.GetPositionNames();
  std::cout << "Plant position names: ";
  const auto& position_names = plant.GetPositionNames();
  for (const auto& name : position_names) {
    std::cout << name << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  Toppra toppra(trajectory_first_pass, plant, gridpoints);

  VectorXd lower_velocity_limit = VectorXd::Constant(plant.num_positions(), -1.0);
  VectorXd upper_velocity_limit = VectorXd::Constant(plant.num_positions(), 1.0);
  toppra.AddJointVelocityLimit(lower_velocity_limit, upper_velocity_limit);

  auto optimized_trajectory = toppra.SolvePathParameterization();

  // Create a TrajectorySource system that outputs the trajectory.
  if (optimized_trajectory) {
    // Create a TrajectorySource system that outputs the trajectory.
    auto trajectory_source = builder.AddSystem<drake::systems::TrajectorySource<double>>(*optimized_trajectory);
    builder.Connect(trajectory_source->get_output_port(), station->GetInputPort("iiwa_position"));
  } else {
    // Handle the case when the optimization fails.
    std::cerr << "TOPPRA optimization failed." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }


  
  geometry::DrakeVisualizerd::AddToBuilder(
      &builder, station->GetOutputPort("query_object"));

  auto lcm = builder.AddSystem<systems::lcm::LcmInterfaceSystem>();

  auto iiwa_command_subscriber = builder.AddSystem(
      systems::lcm::LcmSubscriberSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_iiwa_command>(
          "IIWA_COMMAND", lcm));
  auto iiwa_command =
      builder.AddSystem<manipulation::kuka_iiwa::IiwaCommandReceiver>();
  builder.Connect(iiwa_command_subscriber->get_output_port(),
                  iiwa_command->get_message_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_position_measured"),
                  iiwa_command->get_position_measured_input_port());


  auto iiwa_status =
      builder.AddSystem<manipulation::kuka_iiwa::IiwaStatusSender>();
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_position_commanded"),
                  iiwa_status->get_position_commanded_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_position_measured"),
                  iiwa_status->get_position_measured_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_velocity_estimated"),
                  iiwa_status->get_velocity_estimated_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_torque_commanded"),
                  iiwa_status->get_torque_commanded_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_torque_measured"),
                  iiwa_status->get_torque_measured_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("iiwa_torque_external"),
                  iiwa_status->get_torque_external_input_port());
  auto iiwa_status_publisher = builder.AddSystem(
      systems::lcm::LcmPublisherSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_iiwa_status>(
          "IIWA_STATUS", lcm, 0.005 /* publish period */));
  builder.Connect(iiwa_status->get_output_port(),
                  iiwa_status_publisher->get_input_port());

  // Receive the WSG commands.
  auto wsg_command_subscriber = builder.AddSystem(
      systems::lcm::LcmSubscriberSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_schunk_wsg_command>(
          "SCHUNK_WSG_COMMAND", lcm));
  auto wsg_command =
      builder.AddSystem<manipulation::schunk_wsg::SchunkWsgCommandReceiver>();
  builder.Connect(wsg_command_subscriber->get_output_port(),
                  wsg_command->GetInputPort("command_message"));
  builder.Connect(wsg_command->get_position_output_port(),
                  station->GetInputPort("wsg_position"));
  builder.Connect(wsg_command->get_force_limit_output_port(),
                  station->GetInputPort("wsg_force_limit"));

  // Publish the WSG status.
  auto wsg_status =
      builder.AddSystem<manipulation::schunk_wsg::SchunkWsgStatusSender>();
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("wsg_state_measured"),
                  wsg_status->get_state_input_port());
  builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort("wsg_force_measured"),
                  wsg_status->get_force_input_port());
  auto wsg_status_publisher = builder.AddSystem(
      systems::lcm::LcmPublisherSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_schunk_wsg_status>(
          "SCHUNK_WSG_STATUS", lcm, 0.05 /* publish period */));
  builder.Connect(wsg_status->get_output_port(0),
                  wsg_status_publisher->get_input_port());

  // Publish the camera outputs.
  if (FLAGS_publish_cameras) {
    auto image_encoder = builder.AddSystem<
        systems::sensors::ImageToLcmImageArrayT>();
    for (const auto& camera_name : station->get_camera_names()) {
      // RGB
      const std::string rgb_name = "camera_" + camera_name + "_rgb_image";
      const auto& rgb_output = station->GetOutputPort(rgb_name);
      const auto& rgb_input =
          image_encoder->DeclareImageInputPort<
              systems::sensors::PixelType::kRgba8U>(rgb_name);
      builder.Connect(rgb_output, rgb_input);
      // Depth
      const std::string depth_name = "camera_" + camera_name + "_depth_image";
      const auto& depth_output = station->GetOutputPort(depth_name);
      const auto& depth_input =
          image_encoder->DeclareImageInputPort<
              systems::sensors::PixelType::kDepth16U>(depth_name);
      builder.Connect(depth_output, depth_input);
    }
    const double fps = 30.0;
    auto image_publisher = builder.AddSystem(
        systems::lcm::LcmPublisherSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_image_array>(
            "DRAKE_RGBD_CAMERA_IMAGES", lcm, 1.0 / fps));
    builder.Connect(image_encoder->image_array_t_msg_output_port(),
                    image_publisher->get_input_port());
  }

  // Publish the point clouds.
  if (FLAGS_publish_point_cloud) {
    for (const auto& camera_name : station->get_camera_names()) {
      const std::string cloud_name = "camera_" + camera_name + "_point_cloud";
      auto cloud_encoder = builder.AddSystem<perception::PointCloudToLcm>();
      const double fps = 5.0;
      auto cloud_publisher = builder.AddSystem(
          systems::lcm::LcmPublisherSystem::Make<drake::lcmt_point_cloud>(
              "DRAKE_POINT_CLOUD_" + camera_name, lcm, 1.0 / fps));
      builder.Connect(station->GetOutputPort(cloud_name),
                      cloud_encoder->get_input_port());
      builder.Connect(cloud_encoder->get_output_port(),
                      cloud_publisher->get_input_port());
    }
  }

  // builder.Connect(trajectory_source->get_output_port(),
  //               station->GetInputPort("iiwa_position"));

  auto diagram = builder.Build();

  systems::Simulator<double> simulator(*diagram);
//   Set the initial starting position if provided via command-line flag
  auto context = station->CreateDefaultContext();
  if(!FLAGS_iiwa_starting_position.empty()) {
    VectorXd starting_position = parse_starting_position(FLAGS_iiwa_starting_position);
    auto& station_context = diagram->GetMutableSubsystemContext(*station, &simulator.get_mutable_context());
    station->SetIiwaPosition(&station_context, starting_position);
  }
  VectorXd default_positions = plant.GetPositions(*context);
  std::cout << "Plant positions: ";
  for (const auto& position : default_positions) {
    std::cout << position << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  simulator.Initialize();
  simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(FLAGS_target_realtime_rate);
  simulator.AdvanceTo(FLAGS_duration);



  return 0;
}

}  // namespace
}  // namespace manipulation_station
}  // namespace examples
}  // namespace drake

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return drake::examples::manipulation_station::do_main(argc, argv);
}


Ah, looks like GetSystems() in the documentation for Diagrams might provide the subplant that I want. Will report back when progress has been made.

I don't think Drake supports operating on a subset of states in the plant in the same way that you can operate on a subsystem. (Toppra definitely doesn't support it.)
Best practice for this sort of situation is to create an additional plant that only contains the robot, and use that plant for Toppra. This is also done when adding an InverseDynamicsController (which needs to do physics calculations), or when doing trajectory optimization when you want to ignore the motion of objects in the environment.
